# BibLaTex with APA citation style?

Tags: biblatex, apa7

I basically want LaTeX to do following: https://www.mendeley.com/guides/apa-citation-guide

So everytime I do \cite{source} I get (author et al, year) out. Instead of the weird [1] or [name] tags. And if there is no author, it should do following (title, year).

Comment: did you try biblatex-apa?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. It's hard to tell what you're actually trying without showing any code (a minimal document that shows the bibliography related commands/packages you are using.) The linked question provides two ways to achieve APA style, one using `bibtex` and `apacite` and the other using `biblatex-apa` and `biber`. If you don't need proper APA style, but just one that is generic author/year then there are various other options.